# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Pearson]
[image: yisela]
[image: Alan]
[image: JohnB]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections in several weeks.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

**EDIT:** Please welcome our newest Pro-Tems, Alan and Farray! :D

**EDIT 2:** Please welcome your newest mod, **yisela**!

**EDIT 3:** Please welcome your newest mod, **JohnB**!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome aboard Alan, it's nice to have you:-)

Comment: Many thanks! I'm sure I'll be leaning on you all for a bit while I learn the ropes, being a relative newcomer to the SE community. I'm up for whatever I can do to help the site flourish, so please let me know what I can to be of service.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Congrats on the nifty diamond!  :)

Comment: Thanks, Farray. It's all a bit new, yet... but here's to major growth in 2012, eh?

Comment: Congratulations Alan this what you always deserved from the first day :)

Comment: congrats @AlanGilbertson!

Comment: I for one welcome our new design overlord. ;) Tante auguri, Alan!

Answer (score 3):

Congrats Yisela!  High-fives all around and all that.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Farray! I'll do my best to help in everything I can :)

Comment: Cool! I had a feeling Yisela was destined to become a moderator... :) Glad to see it happen!

Answer (score 2):

A warm welcome to **Farray** for gallantly stepping up to be one of the team. :)

Comment: Now I don't have to keep responding to his flags all the time;-)

Comment: Heh heh heh yes he can handle his own flags! :P

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations John!! It's really nice to have you in the diamond team ;)