# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Graphic Design's [1st moderator election](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Gramps] [image: JonB] [image: Yisela]

They'll be taking over for [the existing crew](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Be sure to thank [the moderators pro tempore](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) who served this community during the beta: PearsonArtPhoto, Yisela, Alan Gilbertson, JohnB, Philip Regan, Jaips and Farray.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6706546671091712/0).

Answer (score 9):

Yes I would also like to thank the moderators who served beta:

- PearsonArtPhoto
- Alan Gilbertson
- Philip Regan
- Jaips
- Farray

You guys did excellent work and thank you for contributing to Stack's Graphic Design board.